# Missing lock nut part on Dura Ace WH-7900 wheels

Tags: wheels, shimano, parts, hub

Not sure what to call it, but a couple of my wheels are missing the grippy washer thing that sits on the lock nut. They seem to be attached to the lock nut to begin with, but they just fall off after a while and get lost when swapping wheels.

Can they be replaced?  If so, where can I find the replacement part?

With:

[image: with]

Without:

[image: without]

Comment: I think the whole thing is called the "Left hand lock bolt unit" (Shimano part number Y3DZ98040 for Dura-ace 9000). If you go to Shimano's website, look up the hub you have and look at the EV file, it will give you the part number.

Comment: I was hoping for the individual part, since the complete lock nut unit costs £40!

Comment: If you do find something, suggest you find some way to hold it on.  A blob ov f thick grease might do but not on friction surfaces.  Maybe some glue, or even a short fat piece of heatshrink over the outside ?

Comment: @Criggie I'm intending to try this: https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/hub-spares/shimano-duraace-fh7800-rear-right-lock-nut-m15-y3b998020/ The serrated ring on the top seems like what I need (and it's considerably cheaper than the complete cone assembly), so hopefully I'll be able to separate it from that part.  I was thinking of using some sort of epoxy to fix it in place, since it's not even supposed to come off!  I'll post an update when I have results.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the washer in your photo may be a "Wedge-Lock" washer like those available here: http://www.mcmaster.com/#standard-washers/=xhptlp
[image: Wedge-lock washer from McMaster Carr]

They appear to sell under the names "Heico-Lock" & "Nord-Lock".
This may be a UK source: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/fasteners-fixings/nuts-washers/locking-anti-vibration-washers/

I should note that there very well may be a similar looking shimano specific part that functions differently & that I am not familiar with. I'm basing this suggestion solely on appearances.

If someone knows that these are in fact not the same as the item pictured by the OP, please enlighten me!

EDIT: To add further to possible resources, at the bottom of this page: http://www.heico-lock.co.uk/products.html There is a list of "Wedge Lock Nuts & Wheel Nuts" (Nuts with an integrated washer half). I do not see any resale links though...